# TFS 2013 EPIC not available

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

My TFS version is 2013.4 and I need EPIC `workitem` type in the Scrum 2013.4 process template.

I was trying to follow the instructions here but EPIC.XML is not found in the process template. Can anyone please let me know will I be able to make the following changes to get the EPICS? Where should I download the EPIC.XML file to import it?
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/09/16/configuring-the-epics-for-upgraded-team-projects-in-team-foundation-server-tfs-2015/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TFS 2013 did not have an epic work item type.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/define-features-epics) Upgrade to a modern version of TFS.

Although you may be able to backport the work item type into prior versions of TFS, you won't have any of the additional features that were released in TFS 2015 around backlog management.